# Eight students are to be seated around a circular table. B is sitting next to either A or C. How many arrangements do we have?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Two seatings are considered the same arrangement if each student has the same student to their right in both seatings.

The solution I think will be:

---

When A or C seat next to B, we have 2 times condition

Then another side of B only have 5 choices (total 8 – A/C 1- another side cannot be A/C -1 – B –1)=8-1-1-1=5

The rest of the seats could have 5! Choice

Sum them together, we have 5*5!*2= 1200

Comment: Can $B$ sit between $A$ and $C$? Or is exactly one of $A$ and $C$ allowed to be next to $B$?

Comment: Based on the question, either...or should means exactly one of A or C seat next to B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not considered on which side of person $B$ person $A$ or $C$ sits.

Also, in mathematics, the word "or" is usually used in the inclusive sense.  The statement $p$ OR $q$ is true if $p$ is true, $q$ is true, or both statements are true.

Since the English construction "either ... or" suggests two mutually exclusive events, we first consider the question under the interpretation that exactly one of person $A$ or person $C$ sits next to person $B$.

> Eight people are to be seated around a circular table, including persons $A$, $B$, and $C$.  In how many ways can they be seated if exactly one of person $A$ or person $C$ sits next to person $B$?

Seat $B$.  Choose whether person $A$ or person $C$ sits next to $B$.  Suppose person $A$ sits next to person $B$.  Then person $A$ can sit to the left or right of person $B$.  Person $C$ can be seated in five ways since two seats are occupied and person $C$ cannot sit next to person $B$ if person $A$ is next to person $B$.  Arrange the remaining five people in the remaining five seats. There are 
$$\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{5}{1}5!$$
distinguishable seating arrangements if exactly one of person $A$ or person $C$ sits next to person $B$.

> Eight people are to be seated around a circular table, including persons $A$, $B$, and $C$.  In how many ways can they be seated if person $A$ or person $C$ sits next to person $B$?

Seat $B$.  Suppose person $A$ sits next to person $B$.  Then person $A$ sits to the left or right of person $B$.  Arrange the remaining six people in the remaining six seats.  There are
$$\binom{2}{1}6!$$
such seating arrangements.

By symmetry, there are also
$$\binom{2}{1}6!$$
seating arrangements in which person $C$ sits next to person $B$.

However, if we add these two cases, we will have counted each seating arrangement in which both person $A$ and person $C$ sit next to person $B$ twice, once for each way we could have designated one of them as the person who sits next to person $B$.  We only want to count such cases once, so we must subtract them from the total.

Seat person $B$.  If both person $A$ and person $C$ sit next to person $B$, they can be seated in two ways, depending on which one of them sits to person $B$'s left.  Seat the remaining five people in the remaining five seats.  This can be done in 
$$2!5!$$
ways.

Hence, there are
$$\binom{2}{1}6! + \binom{2}{1}6! - 2!5!$$
seating arrangements in which person $A$ or person $C$ sits next to person $B$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. I misunderstood the question before.